# Convergent sequence of characteristic functions with continuous integrable limit.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, fourier-analysis, characteristic-functions

Suppose $\varphi_{n}$
  is a sequence of characteristic functions converging pointwise to a function $\varphi$
  which is continuous and absolutely integrable. I want to show that $\varphi$
  is the Fourier Transform of a probability density. I know that convergence of $\varphi_{n}$
  pointwise implies weak* convergence of a sequence of corresponding random-variables to the RV whose chf is $\varphi$
  but I'm not sure if that helps.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas (the first theorem)

Comment: @Augustin how do I show that this $f$ defined in the statement is a density, I would have to show it's non-negative and integrates to 1 on the real line.